# quicksight calculate group average without duplicate value

Tags: amazon-quicksight

if i have a dataset with two table

Table A

| id | category | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | cat1 | 10 |
| 234 | cat1 | 55 |
| 345 | cat3 | 89 |
| 567 | cat2 | 22 |
| 789 | cat3 | 43 |

Table B

| id | refA | other data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 123 | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet |
| 002 | 123 | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet |
| 003 | 234 | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet |
| 004 | 234 | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet |
| 005 | 234 | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet |

i need to calculate the average of value for every category.
How can i do that without counting the duplicate value that quicksight create after the join of the two table?